# When testing NHibernate with a SQLite In Memory configuration, how do you create another database?

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

We have an app that uses NHibernate/FluentNHibernate with a `MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString` pointed at our SQL environment. The SQL servers have several database and we can connect to different databases by using a convention like so:

```
public class FactseDatabaseConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.EntityType.Namespace.EndsWith("Model.OtherEntities"))
        {
            instance.Schema("OtherDatabase.dbo");
        }
    }
}
```

This works and the correct queries are generated to access the `OtherDatabase`.  The problem comes in when we want to test using a `SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory()` with our SessionFactory. The Persistence tests fail when SQLite is preparing:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQL logic error or missing database
unknown database OtherDatabase
```

This is the command it generates:

```
create table OtherDatabse.dbo_my_other_entity_table (
        Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
        ... other properties
)
```

Is there a way I can change my `SQLiteConfiguration` to have it create 2 in-memory databases and, if so, how?  Or should I just create a separate Session for testing these other entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this very same problem - (no longer since we moved from Sqlite to Sql Server LocalDB for tests).

I do still have the code, what we did was provide a component which configures whether to use schemas or not, thus:

```
public class SqlLiteMappingsHelper : IMappingsHelper
    {
        public string TextColumnTableSpecification
        {
            get
            {
                // see sqlite faqs re: all varchars are very large whatever you specify
                // http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9
                return "nvarchar(10)";
            }
        }

        public bool SchemasEnabled
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

(and one similar for sql server with `SchemasEnabled = true`) - in the web app you tell your IoC container to use the sql server one and in your test app you use the Sqlite one. Then in your convention:

```
public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
{
    var helper = IoC.get<IMappingsHelper>();
    if (instance.EntityType.Namespace.EndsWith("Model.OtherEntities") && helper.SchemasEnabled)
    {
        instance.Schema("OtherDatabase.dbo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jenson-button-event, this may work. Before I try it, do you have any info you can share on the local SQL solution?  I may prefer to try that.

Comment: It's an in-memory edition of MSSQL Express 2012 created for developers.  Here's an [MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) about it, and a link to [download MSSQL Express 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx).  You can also get it through an MSDN subscription if you have one.  Just search for LocalDB in the MSDN subscriber downloads.